# Create a new column in pandas dataframe based on multiple conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements

I have a dataframe like the one below, and I have to create a new column `year_val` that is equal to the values of `col2016` through `col2019` based on the `Years` column, so that the value for `year_val` will be the value of `col####` when `Years` is equal to the suffix of `col####`

```py
import pandas as pd

sampleDF = pd.DataFrame({'Years':[2016,2016,2017,2017,2018,2018,2019,2019],
                        'col2016':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],
                        'col2017':[9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16],
                        'col2018':[17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24],
                        'col2019':[25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32]})

sampleDF['year_val'] = ?????
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.lookup`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.lookup.html) with change values in `Years` column with prepend `col` and cast to string:

```
sampleDF['year_val'] = sampleDF.lookup(sampleDF.index, 'col' + sampleDF['Years'].astype(str))

print (sampleDF)
   Years  col2016  col2017  col2018  col2019  year_val
0   2016        1        9       17       25         1
1   2016        2       10       18       26         2
2   2017        3       11       19       27        11
3   2017        4       12       20       28        12
4   2018        5       13       21       29        21
5   2018        6       14       22       30        22
6   2019        7       15       23       31        31
7   2019        8       16       24       32        32
```

EDIT: If check definition of `lookup` function:

> result = [df.get_value(row, col) for row, col in zip(row_labels, col_labels)]

you can modify it with `try-except` statement with [`Series.at`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.at.html) for prevent:

> FutureWarning: get_value is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use .at[] or .iat[] accessors instead
>         oup.append(sampleDF.at[row, col] )

```
sampleDF = pd.DataFrame({'Years':[2015,2016,2017,2017,2018,2018,2019,2019],
                        'col2016':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],
                        'col2017':[9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16],
                        'col2018':[17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24],
                        'col2019':[25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32]})

print (sampleDF)
   Years  col2016  col2017  col2018  col2019
0   2015        1        9       17       25
1   2016        2       10       18       26
2   2017        3       11       19       27
3   2017        4       12       20       28
4   2018        5       13       21       29
5   2018        6       14       22       30
6   2019        7       15       23       31
7   2019        8       16       24       32
```

---

```
out= []
for row, col in zip(sampleDF.index, 'col' + sampleDF['Years'].astype(str)):
    try:
        out.append(sampleDF.at[row, col] )
    except KeyError:
        out.append(np.nan)

sampleDF['year_val'] = out
print (sampleDF)
   Years  col2016  col2017  col2018  col2019  year_val
0   2015        1        9       17       25       NaN
1   2016        2       10       18       26       2.0
2   2017        3       11       19       27      11.0
3   2017        4       12       20       28      12.0
4   2018        5       13       21       29      21.0
5   2018        6       14       22       30      22.0
6   2019        7       15       23       31      31.0
7   2019        8       16       24       32      32.0
```

Comment: How to I ignore values that are not found? Like if I have 2020 values on the Year colum, but do not have a `col_2020`